# How can I change object value with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a foreign exchange application and while choosing the currency; I am doing mathematical operation as (selected currency / other currencies). The values I get come in the form of key value from [apiden](http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=0dbd69e58e2f4c63254e5bb52e368079&format=1). I keep the incoming data in an object.
Here is what I'm trying to do: Change the value of the selected currency by dividing it into other currencies. I'm just asking how can I change the values in the object?

```
this.rates['value']  = Object.values(this.rates).map(data=> (this.chooseValue / (data as any)));
this.rates['key'] = Object.values(this.rates).map(data => data);
```

I tried this but it didn't work.
By the way, I do the application with angular.

Comment: So you want to update only one selected currency value from `rates` object, rest all currencies should remain as its correct?

Comment: All currencies will be updated according to the selected currency.This is what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
const rates = {
  AED: 4.270181,
  AFN: 89.608722,
  ALL: 123.953995,
  AMD: 564.185821,
  ANG: 2.091704,
  AOA: 728.73475,
  ARS: 88.108818,
  AUD: 1.6493,
  AWG: 2.092719
}

let newRates = {};
const chooseValue = 2; // whatever value you choose to divide.

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(rates)) {
  newRates = {
    ...newRates,
    [key]: value/chooseValue
  }
}

console.log(newRates)
```

Comment: @JosephScott glad to help you can upvote the answer it will help other colleagues as well